# Android Facebook Error: Failed to generate preview for user

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to post a Custom Open graph story in Facebook integration with SDK 4.5 , but i am not able to post it. i have created a object and action in my code

I am getting this error:

```
Failed to generate preview for user.com.facebook.http.
protocol.ApiException: [code] 100 [message]: (#100) 
App xxxx is not allowed to create actions of type  
restaurant:Wants To Visit for user xxxxx [extra]:
```

My code:

```
public void SongRequest(){
    try {
        // Create an object
        ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
        .putString("og:type", "restaurant.restaurant")
        .putString("og:title", "Peddlers")
        .putString("og:image", "https://scontent.fdel1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/11996901_943588275699701_6661729706633501716_n.jpg?oh=5ebb6e29eff2009e0f4c68f86b06923d&oe=56A8B7CE")
        .putString("og:description", "Peddlers Under The Big Ben")
        .putString("restaurant:contact_info:street_address", "1601 Willow Rd.")
        .putString("restaurant:contact_info:locality", "Menlo Park")
        .putString("restaurant:contact_info:region", "California")
        .putString("restaurant:contact_info:postal_code", "160022")
        .putString("restaurant:contact_info:country_name", "India")
        .putString("restaurant:contact_info:email", "brian@example.com")
        .putString("restaurant:contact_info:phone_number", "212-555-1234")
        .putString("restaurant:contact_info:website", "https://www.facebook.com/peddlersrock")
        .putString("place:location:latitude", "30.70516586")
        .putString("place:location:longitude", "76.8010025")
        .putString("og:url", "https://www.facebook.com/CompetentGroove")
        .build();

        //Then create an action and link the object to the action.
        // Create an action
        ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("restaurant.wants_to_visit")
            .putObject("restaurant", object)
            .build();

        //Finally, create the content model to represent the Open Graph story.
        // Create the content
        ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("restaurant")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

        //Present the Share dialog by using the show method on ShareDialog.

        ShareDialog.show(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this, content);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Graph Stories.Exception", e.toString());
    }
}
```